# Remove a particular tag(<xs:any>) from xsd file using C#

Tags: c#, regex, xsd

I am new to XSD. I have a XSD file where following is appearing couple of times in a xsd file.

```
<xs:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbound">
  <xs:annotation>
     <xs:documentation> blah blah blah</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
</xs:any>
```

I have to remove this part from a XSD file where these "any" tag is there using C#.I have tried using System.Xml.Schema but failed bcoz this snippet can be at any level.Then I tried with regex which starts with 'xs:any' and end with '/xs:any' with angle brakets also, but failed to write the exact pattern . Please help me with a solution. it may System.Xml.Schema or Regex or any other ways.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML for this:

```
XNamespace xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
var doc = XDocument.Load(your xsd file);
doc.Descendants(xs + "any").Remove();
```